# Is there any way to find out if a display color depth is native 8 bit or 6 + 2 FRC?

Tags: display, colors, external-display, color-depth

Consider a monitor whose specifications say "Color depth: 8 bit" on any website where you buy it from.

But the thing is, it can be 6 + 2 FRC OR native 8 bit. I recently learned this thing. The user manuals don't exactly specify these things. Some of them do, some don't. This is what I realized with my research.

For example, BenQ GW2480 monitor shows "Color bit: 8" on its specifications page (In fact all of their monitors show at least 8 bit on their BenQ Europe website). But when I checked its reviews online and display specifications on many other sites, they mentioned it has 6 + 2 FRC/dithering color depth. So it isn't native 8 bit.

Now, I have a laptop and in Windows 10 (at least) you can check this thing. For example, my laptop shows 6 bit:

[image]

Now I want to understand that if I buy that "8 bit" monitor, would Windows show exact physical color depth? If it's native 8 bit, I'm sure it will show 8 bit. But if it is 6 + 2 FRC, would it still show 8 or 6 bit, I'm not sure.

**So this is one way to check color depth but I'm not sure how reliable it is in case of "8 bit". Are there any other ways to find out that if you have the monitor?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the technical documentation of the monitor is not specific enough
to answer the question, you could:

- Search for third-party technical reviews and user cases
- Pay attention to the backlight technology used in the TV.
  For example:

  - Supreme UHD Dimming : 8 bit + FRC
  - Ultimate UHD Dimming (pro) : 10 bit.
- If the monitor has an On-Screen Display (OSD), check if the menu
  contains an entry for FRC.
- The website
  [The Lagom LCD monitor test pages](http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/black.php)
  contains a page with 255 rectangles for all the levels of black
  from 1 to 255.
  Looking carefully, you might see quickly moving patterns inside some
  rectangle, which indicates FRC.
  A purposefully exaggerated example is included in the article
  (ensure that GIF animation is enabled in the browser):

  [image]